# Where to find csc.exe in .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-framework-version

I try to find `csc.exe` to add this to `PATH` system variable. I have been install `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK`.
[image]
[image]

Why I don't see v4.5 in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64?
Where to find csc.exe in .NET Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSC present in 4.0 folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319) is also csc of 4.5.
Path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe is for 64 bit version of framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
# In PowerShell
# Dotnet's CSc.exe path:
[String]$cscPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()), "csc.exe");
Write-Output $cscPath
```